# Keeping ratio of ImageView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-relativelayout

I have to set background image of `ImageView` and after time to set imageSource of this ImageView.

So what I did is to set image view background with setBackgroundImage(). 
Also I set 
`adjustViewBounds = true` and `scaleType = "fitCenter"`, and `height = 55dp` and `width = wrap content`.

So I expected at first time(when I set only set background) to have this scenario - the view will be with the same ration and will fit the smallest - width or height (of course if height is larger than 55dp, it will be scaled). But the result is scalled image (when the image should be larger than 55 dp i.e. height is scaled). The image is in RelativeLayout. Unfortunately, I cannot post the whole code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subclass that `ImageView` and override `onLayout()` to keep width/height ratio like so:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    double ratio = ...

    int width = right - left;
    int height = ratio * width;
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = this.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = height;
    params.width = width;
    this.setLayoutParams(params);
    this.setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, top + height);
}
```

Comment: I need a little more help. I try this and it didn't work.

   height = bottom - top;
            width = (int)(ratio * height);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.width = width;
            params.height = height;

            this.setLayoutParams(params);
            this.setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        

        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, left + width, top + height);

Comment: @DPM: What is the surrounding layout? What params has that and so forth?

Comment: Sorry, for the answer`s delay. The view is in RelativeLayout, with fixed height and width = MATCH_PARENT. So in tablets it is is scaled and I don't want to be like this. Actually I tried to override onMeasure. I use the minimum ot getLayoutParams().height, get suggestedHeight and MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec) and this works, but in older phones it is obvious that it lags a lot more. And the lag is after the view is showed and when I animating it. The weird is that its onMeasure is not called during the animation. So I don't have any idea why is that.

Comment: And why should I override onLayout ? Woudn't it be better to override onMeasure ? ImageView doesn't have childs . I think onLayout is unnecesary.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because, as i remember, onMeasure is part of the whole measuring mechanism where you don't necessary want to mess with. I found that is works to set the layouted, not the measured dimensions, as measuring also is involved in distributing the available space, like for `LinearLayout`s' children with weighted `LayoutParams`.

Comment: Sorry for answer delaying.
I tried difference ways. super.onLayout call View`s method which is empty.
I try to create custom layout (extend FramLayout) and to put the view in it and to call layout on the child. This works, but it doen't center this view, I don't know why. The left is 5 and the right is 135. The view should be centered with width = 70 I call child.layout() with left = 35 and right = 105 and it is like it translates the view. Like there is padding, but there isn't . Why this can be like this ? I use (left + right - desiredWidth) / 2 for left bound of the view. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DPM I don't think you can set the position of your child within the parent in `onLayout()`. It's merely called to inform the view about the size it can have, and you can change it 'in child view domain'. But, again, setting the layout of a child within it's parent is clearly the parent's job, and only the parent's.

Comment: @DPM So if you want to set size and position, you should enclose the child in a RelativeLayout and set the layout params for the child to be centered. That way the rel layout handles the centering, but the size thing is still the child's job. If your original parent (i.e. the parent of the helping relative layout) can handle the centering for you here, you could save a layout instance. but with the helping one, this certainly will work gracefully.